# Unable to access 'https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

Ok tried the ealier versions of spfx and had no issues. Thought I would try RC0 with samples but struggling to clone locally, both at work on home ( no proxy) on my dev laptop.  Any ideas

```
λ git clone https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts.git
```

> Cloning into 'sp-dev-fx-webparts'... fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts.git/': Failed to
>   connect to 172.17.59.11 port 8080: Timed out
>
> D:\Box Sync\yo λ ping 172.17.59.11
>
> Pinging 172.17.59.11 with 32 bytes of data: **Request timed out.**

Comment: Everything works just fine for me. It's extremely rare situation if github is not available. Check your proxy\dns cache\internet.

Comment: Looks more like an internet connection/speed issue ? ISP block ? Works absolutely fine at my end. If you have any azure VM , try inside that. Check this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zHxF.png

Comment: I have tried with and without a proxy at work.  I would think DNS and or timeout settings  if the simple ping worked. Also disabled AV temporarily .  GIT on Visual Studio Online works fine. Yes I could try Azure.

Comment: Got a mate near London to ping the ip address with an app on his phone called ping .. no response. he pinged his router and got a response.  I am thinking this is a  UK thing going on ... maybe country blocking - early Brexit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it - the answer was obvious - I hadn't twigged that I was staring at the proxy address .  Then I remembered having to set the proxy in Git for  VC code when last  connected to the proxy. Hence, just needed to undo this.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```